# listview item as checkbox

Tags: listview, checkbox, jquery-mobile

Is there an elegant way to display listview items as checkboxes, such that the only visual difference is the checkbox-icon (very similar to how checkboxes are displayed within a fieldset with data-role="controlgroup", except for the margin at the top and bottom margin and the rounded corners)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta 2:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

> **Checkboxes and Radio buttons: New, Simpler design**
>
> Now onto fun fun stuff: the previous design for checkboxes or radio
>   buttons highlighted the entire button background to the active state.
>   We’ve wanted to tweak this for some time because having the full
>   button switch tothe active state could be a bit overwhelming visually,
>   especially on a check list with multiple items selected.
>
> To make these controls a bit simpler visually and also fall in-line
>   with standard UI conventions, now just the check or radio form element
>   flips to the active state instead of the whole button. Note that the
>   horizontal, grouped check and radio groups still flip the while label
>   to the active state color because we hide the form element in these
>   cases.

[image]